# MySQL group by fill gaps

Tags: mysql

I need to group by a field and fill missing information if any.

For example, we have a `test` table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test` (
    `name` VARCHAR(100), `description` VARCHAR(100)
);
```

For this table, we have the following records:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `description`, `email`)
VALUES ('John', '', ''),
VALUES ('John', 'Description #1', ''),
VALUES ('John', 'Description #2', ''),
VALUES ('John', '', 'john@example.com'),
VALUES ('John', '', '');
```

I need to select all entries on this table grouped by `name` and filling gaps, such as `description` (in this case, it should use 'Description #2' as it is the latest non-empty value for `description`. Same goes for `email`, it should return 'john@example.com'.

How should I select these values?
PS: the actual table have several columns, so it would be good to not modify the `SELECT` statement.

My current select is:

```
SELECT `name`, `description` FROM `test` GROUP BY `name`;
```

The problem is it will always use the first occurrence values. I need to "merge" all values based on latest non-empty insertion.

**Each column may end up using values from different entries.**

Expected output:

> ```
> ____________________________________________
> | name | description    | email            |
> --------------------------------------------
> | John | Description #2 | john@example.com |
> --------------------------------------------
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.  What does this table look like after applying your logic?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added

Comment: As the answer below hints at, you really need some column which tells us a timestamp associated with each record.  For your exact sample data, just taking the max of each column would work.  But, this would likely fail with your real data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make explicit what does "last" actually mean. The records you inserted don't have any specific order, so you'll have to add either an autoincrementing id, or something like `created_at` date.

Then, you can choose the right records using:

```
  SELECT `name`, `description`
    FROM `test`
GROUP BY `name`
  HAVING `created_at` = MAX(`created_at`)
```

For the non-empty part, you'll have to filter them using `WHERE description<>''`.

Comment: What if the latest `created_at` have empty value? I need the last non-empty value for each column.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Added the note about filtering empty entries.

Comment: just added a better example.